# Convergent sequence of $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $x_n=\frac{1}{n}$, for $n = 1,2,3, . . .$

> is {$x_n$} convergent ?

Solution:
the terms in the sequence $1, \frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac {1}{4}, . . .$ get closer to $0$ as $n$ gets larger, so the sequence converges to $0$. Anyone can complete the proof that {$x_n$} convergent?

Comment: The solution is correct. You should start with the definition of "convergence". Can you recall it? Then we can solve this question together.

Comment: You have to show that the $x_n$ get as close to zero as you want (i.e. under some $\epsilon$) as of a certain $N$. More precisely, if you set $\epsilon$, it must be posible to find a suitable $N(\epsilon)$.

Answer (score 1):

Given any $\epsilon>0$, however small, there must exist an integer $N$ so large that $N > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$, i.e. $\frac{1}{N} < \epsilon$, and of course for all $n \geq N$, $x_n = \frac{1}{n} < \epsilon$, which is the exact definition of convergence.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

Merely stating "get closer" isn't enough. For instance, the terms $1+\dfrac1n$ do get closer and closer to $0$, but they in fact converge to $1$.

The trick is to show that they get *as close as one wants*, which is expressed by $|x_n-0|<\epsilon$ for any positive $\epsilon$. And this must hold from a certain $n$ onwards, which may depend on $\epsilon$.